# Why my calculated NQPD value is different than sDNA calucated?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sdna

I want to calculate the NQPD value (Network Quantity Penalized of Distance) by my hand, and then compare it with snda calculated. But I found that I can't the value same as what sdna calculated.

My case is as the following: 
[image: link_a]
Assume all the links length of this network is 500 meters. While calcualte the NQPD value for the link A with raidus 600 meters and angle metric, totally 7 links should be considered(please refer the bold links in the picture).

In my understanding, the **NQPD Angle R600 =1/90+1/90+1/90+1/90=0.0444.**
But the **sDNA result is 0.03148.** Please refer the follwing sDNA result picture. 
[image: sdna R600]

How does the sDNA get that result and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for taking the time to understand this in detail! There are a few oddities in design of the NQPDA measure which may seem illogical at first but bear with me...

Firstly, the calculation you give misses the links to the left and right of A. Note that the angular distance from A to these links is zero, which would make NQPDA equal to infinity, which is not a useful measure. So we chose not to compute it like that.

Instead for computing NQPD Angular, every angular geodesic distance has 180 degrees added to it. If you like you can interpret this as a 90 degree turn to enter, and to leave the network.

Secondly, the calculation above misses the contribution of link A to its own NQPDA. This is approximated as 1/3 the metric distance along link A (whatever the metric) as you can show for a homogeneous link that each point is on average 1/3 of the link length from each other point. (Not all links are homogeneous, e.g. one might have a bend at only one end, but it's only an approximation in any case to make sure no accessible network is left out. This would really matter to you if you had a large weight attached to link A).

The total angular distance along link A is 0, so in this case the approximation is 0/3 which is still 0, but remember like the other angular distances this gets 180 added to it.

So the NQPDA for link A is

```
1/(180+90) * 4       (for the 4 links with 90 degree turns)
+ 1/(180+0) * 2      (for the 2 links with no turn)
+ 1/(180+0/3)        (for A itself)
= 0.03148
```

**A side note on NQPD**

A final note on use of NQPD. NQPD is a gravity measure and if you want to use it to model real data you'll probably want to calibrate it (e.g. set the relative importance of quantity of network vs accessibility of that network using `nqpdn` and `nqpdd` in advanced config). This is computationally expensive for NQPD as the only way is to run lots of models with different values of `nqpdn` and `nqpdd`.

A couple of alternatives exist:

1. make a model using two predictor variables; network quantity (Links, Length or Weight) and Mean Angular Distance. Like any gravity model this can be fitted [using a translog regression and poisson link function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89722/fitting-a-log-or-generalized-linear-model). Having fitted your gravity model you could apply the parameters back to `nqpdn` and `nqpdd` of the NQPD function if you like.
2. using hybrid radius make a multivariate model of network quantity at multiple radius. Switch on banded radius, set an angular radius type, and hence compute e.g. Links accessible within 0-90 degrees, 90-180, 180-360, ... etc, you choose the angular distance bands. You could do it with Length or Weight as well. You can then calibrate a non-parametric distance decay curve using multivariate regression; use something which can handle correlated predictors e.g. ridge regression which is available in sDNA Learn.

None of this should be of concern if you are just using NQPD to visualise network characteristics rather than using it to predict some actual measured quantity.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answering, very useful and clearly.

Comment: But why should add 180 to every angular geodesic distance?  For make 0 degree link computable only?  any other reason?   Thanks!

Comment: Yes, for that reason. If you didn't, then any link which joined directly to another without turns (e.g. a crossroads) would have infinite NQPD, which means the measure isn't very useful. Typically when situations like this arise in statistics an arbitrary constant is added to avoid it e.g. `log(count+1)` rather than `log(count)` when transforming count data. In the current case we choose to make the arbitrary constant equal 180 as that has a reasonable physical interpretation - 90 degree turn to join and leave the network.