# Network Quantity Penalized of Distance in sDNA

Tags: sdna

I'm following up on a question asked on the calculation of the Network Quantity Penalized of Distance (NQPD) with sDNA.

I can calculate the value for the link asked in [Why my calculated NQPD value is different than sDNA calucated?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241925); e.g. the links where the value is 0.031481.

However, for the adjacent values I obtain a different value when calculating the NQPD by hand.

For instance, for the links with a NQPD of 0.024074 I obtain:

```
1/(180+90) * 4 (four links with 90 degree turn)
1/(180+0) * 1 (one link with 0 degree 'turn')
1/(180+0/3) * 1 (self-contribution) 
 = 0.025925926
```

To obtain the value calculated by sDNA I need to adjust the self-contribution of the link to

```
1/(180+0)*2/3
```

Is the self-contribution of these links calculated differently?

[image]

Comment: Am I right in thinking your radius is 600m, in discrete space, and each link is 500m long?